# SQL Query with days of month as columns

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to create a query which will show sales like this:

```
     Jan  Feb  Mar  ...
2011 1253 1381 1973 ...
2012 3124 3829 1823 ...
```

Along the top shows months from Jan to Dec and the left hand column shows the year. The data is SUM'd figures for the entire period of that year/month.

The table holds sales records with totals and datetime field.

I've seen some options for this using UNPIVOT, but I can't get my head around it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some information about your tables and the code you're struggling with please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your table structure, you could do something like

```
select
      year( YT.YourDateColumn ) as SalesYear,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 1, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Jan,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 2, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Feb,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 3, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Mar,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 4, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Apr,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 5, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as May,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 6, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Jun,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 7, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Jul,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 8, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Aug,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 9, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Sep,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 10, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Oct,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 11, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Nov,
      sum( if( month( yt.YourDateColumn ) = 12, YT.SalesAmt, 000000.00 )) as Dec
   from
      YourTable YT
   group by
      year( YT.YourDateColumn )
   order by
      Year( YT.YourDateColumn )
```